# How does one call on this Haskell function?

Tags: haskell, random

This is a function to generate a list of given number of random numbers within a range, but I'm confused on how to call on this function. I think a seed is needed for StdGen, but really appreciate if someone can tell how exactly to call this function.

```
randomList :: (Random a) => (a,a) -> Int -> StdGen -> [a]
randomList bnds n = take n . randomRs bnds
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do g <- getStdGen
          print (randomList (1, 100) 5 g :: [Integer])
```

will output e.g.

```
[42,42,15,7]
```

The `g` is the random number generator, in this case the "global random number generator".
Here's the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random/1.0.0.3/doc/html/System-Random.html)

Comment: Never use `getStdGen`! It is a recipe for certain confusion. Use `newStdGen` instead.

Comment: To clarify, the problem with `getStdGen` is that if you do that twice in a row, you'll get the same numbers each time. Better to use `newStdGen`, which will split the global generator instead of just returning it unmodified.

Comment: @Rotsor Is there any problem with `getStdGen` if you only ever use one generator in a programme?

Comment: Daniel, none I know of. That is a big "if" though.

Answer (score 3):

You supply a range (in the form of a tuple), a number of elements, and an `StdGen`, i.e. `randomList (0,10) 100 gen`, where `gen :: StdGen`. An `StdGen` just represents the standard random number generator, and there are multiple ways to get one:

- [`getStdGen`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random/latest/doc/html/System-Random.html#v%3agetStdGen), which is an IO action returning the global `StdGen`.
- [`mkStdGen`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random/latest/doc/html/System-Random.html#v%3amkStdGen), passing in a seed (as an `Int`). Of course, `mkStdGen seed` will produce the same random numbers for the same `seed`; this is useful if you want deterministic results but, of course, won't help if you want different random numbers each time :)

For example, `getStdGen >>= randomList (0,10) 100` has type `(Random a) => IO [a]`, and produces a list of 100 random numbers from 0 to 10 when executed (for example, by doing `numbers <- getStdGen >>= randomList (0,10) 100` in a `do` block).

However, `randomList` doesn't return the final `StdGen` obtained after the numbers are generated, and so, unless you create a new `StdGen` for each use of it, it'll always return the same results. The action I showed above will produce different results each time the program is run, but if it's used multiple times with the same range over the course of a single run of your program, it'll produce the same numbers each time.

This can be fixed by manually generating the list instead of using `randomRs`; for example:

```
randomList :: (Random a) => (a,a) -> Int -> StdGen -> ([a], StdGen)
randomList _ 0 gen = ([], gen)
randomList bnds n gen = (x:xs, gen'')
  where
    (x, gen') = randomR bnds gen
    (xs, gen'') = randomList bnds (n-1) gen'
```

This can then be used with the global `StdGen` using [`getStdRandom`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random/latest/doc/html/System-Random.html#v%3agetStdRandom); for example:

```
main :: IO ()
main = replicateM_ 10 $ do
    xs <- getStdRandom $ randomList (0,10) 100
    print xs
```

This should produce 10 distinct lists of 100 elements each.