# Haskell - Randomize Float

Tags: haskell

I am trying to call this function that my professor has done but I don't understand how to call the last parameter!

```
ran_lst :: Float -> (Float, Float) -> StdGen -> ([Float], StdGen)
```

I have tried something like:

```
ran_lst 1.0 (1.0,100.00) ?
```

The **?** denotes what should I call inside!

Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one call on this Haskell function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141794/how-does-one-call-on-this-haskell-function)

Comment: @RobinGreen that post is not clear on how should I call the function.

Comment: What is unclear about the answer to that question?

Comment: @RobinGreen my question is how do i call the function, more specifically the last parameter. The post you suggested talks about the Random function. 

When I call my function I have NO IDEA on what to use in the third parameter.

Could you just help? It would be much easier ...

Check this: http://prntscr.com/lmeyyd

Comment: `Random` from the linked post is not a function, it is a type class. It can be read as 'anything that a RNG can produce'. Both your function and the function from the linked post use the same RNG, `StdGen`, and any source of these mentioned in answers there is applicable to your question as well.

Comment: If all you want is to test your function from GHCi, you can use `g <- getStdGen` and then `ran_lst 1.0 (1.0,100.0) g`. Note that this is a *function*, and because of that you'll get the same output if you call it with the same `g`.

Comment: See [the docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html#t:StdGen) for the definition of a `StdGen`.

Comment: @chi that was all I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @chi said, first I need to call `g <- getStdGen` and only then run the function